# Angular 5: Is there anything like $httpParamSerailizer that was available in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am trying to serialize object to query parameters. In `AngularJS` I use `$httpParamSerializer`.

What is available in `Angular 5`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my take on your question. This uses the `HttpParamsOptions` and `HttpParams`. The `HttpParamsOptions` will build out the params by passing it an object in the `fromObject` property. You can see in the comment what that looks like when the API call is made.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpParamsOptions } from '@angular/common/http/src/params';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getThingsWithParams(): any { // you could pass your object in as a function parameter
      const myObject: any = { this: 'thisThing', that: 'thatThing', other: 'otherThing'};
      const httpParams: HttpParamsOptions = { fromObject: myObject } as HttpParamsOptions;
      const options = { params: new HttpParams(httpParams) };
      return this.httpClient.get<any>('http://localhost:34479/api/products/168', options);
      // This is what is sent to the API:
      // http://localhost:34479/api/products/168?this=thisThing&that=thatThing&other=otherThing
  }
}
```

I think this is what you are after. A way to have the parameters build based on the properties of an object.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/530b824faa29460a87c2401bc61d22a7fb56f939/packages/common/http/src/params.ts#L76

Comment: Yes, got it working by looking at the source code of HttParams, it takes 'fromObject'. Thanks for the effort though. Answer accepted.